# Apply changes (group by) on multiple dataframes using for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I have around 33 dataframes (df1, df2, df3, df4 ...) that look like this:

```
Date       Month   Value  
2018-07-16 2018-07     10 
2018-07-17 2018-07     2
2018-07-18 2018-07     4 
2018-07-19 2018-07     45
2018-07-20 2018-07     13
```

and I would like to group each data frame by month, like this:

```
df1 = df1 %>% group_by(Month)%>%
  summarise(
    sd_value = sd(value)
  )
```

How can I do this on all dataframes without repeating it?
Also, I will need to export the results as separate data frames.

I've tried to duplicate some other people's solutions using for loop but doesn't work.
Also, I have all the dataframes separately in my Environment, they are not in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them in list using `mget` with your pattern, loop over them using `lapply` and then `aggregate`

```
list_name <- ls(pattern = "df\\d+")

list_df <- lapply(mget(list_name), function(x) aggregate(Value~Month, x, sd))
list_df

#$df1
#    Month    Value
#1 2018-07 17.45566

#$df2
#    Month    Value
#1 2018-07 185.8744
```

Or if you want to use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

list_df <- map(mget(list_name), 
          . %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(sd_value = sd(Value)))
```

To write them in separate csv's we can use `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x, y) write.csv(x, 
      paste0("path/to/file/", y, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE), list_df, list_name)
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:5, .Label = c("2018-07-16", 
"2018-07-17", "2018-07-18", "2018-07-19", "2018-07-20"), class = "factor"), 
Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2018-07", class = "factor"), 
Value = c(10L, 2L, 4L, 45L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:5, .Label = c("2018-07-16", 
 "2018-07-17", "2018-07-18", "2018-07-19", "2018-07-20"), class = "factor"), 
Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2018-07", class = "factor"), 
Value = c(11L, 2L, 4L, 423L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: it works! but how can I export them out as dataframes?

Comment: @YuiLin Do you want to export them into separate dataframe or one dataframe?

Comment: separate dataframe!

Comment: somehow it didnt work for me and shows error,
```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
 
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection 
```

but thank you a lot!

Comment: @YuiLin Ddi you assign the result to `list_df` and are you changing `"path/to/file/"` to your actual file path ?

Comment: Ahh yes it worked!!
but actually -- sorry if I didnt put this clear, what i meant it so have the dataframe in the environment. Would that be similar?

Comment: @YuiLin For that do `list2env(list_df ,envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d+")), function(x)
            setDT(x)[, .(sd_value = sd(Value)), by = Month])
```